# Is there a word or a combination of words that can describe something waving in all directions?

Tags: word-choice

I was visiting a glass exhibition this afternoon and one piece of glass work caught my eyes. It was composed of hundreds of curved tubes of glass, each  looping around the others until eventually they shape like medusa's hairs. Can you come up with any descriptive expressions for such view?

Comment: So you are looking to describe what exactly? The tubes? The way they were curved? The fact that they were curved into a design? Please specify.

Comment: Bedhead? ([Definition 2](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bedhead))

Comment: Well, yes, obviously ***[quaquaversal](http://onelook.com/?w=quaquaversal&ls=a)***. Duh.

Comment: Did the work have a name?  Did it really look like a nest of serpents?  The concept that is forming in my mind is a three dimensional projection of something in higher dimensions.  Look at these images of [Calabi Yau](https://www.google.com/search?q=calabi+yau+manifold&biw=1119&bih=642&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwi1uvOF-YPRAhXl5oMKHYkwCUsQsAQIKw) manifolds.  Does the work you saw bear any resemblance  to any of these?

Comment: I would naturally say ["Chihuly-like"](https://www.flickr.com/photos/vrot01/12455980645), but then I live near the Mayo Clinic, which is infested with several of these sculptures.  Otherwise, "Medusa-like" or "hydra-like" would be my first attempt at description.

Comment: When hair does this, we call it ***curly***.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, chihuly glass is what I'm talking about. Thank you!

Comment: @ab2 I looked at those images. They do look alike. And I like your simile of "a nest of serpents". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe ***vortex*** is convenient word for you.

Per [Dictionary.com's definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vortex):

> 4. a state of affairs likened to a whirlpool for violent activity, irresistible force, etc.
> 5. something regarded as drawing into its powerful current everything that surrounds it: the vortex of war.
> 6. (in Cartesian philosophy) a rapid rotatory movement of cosmic matter about a center, regarded as accounting for the origin or
>      phenomena of bodies or systems of bodies in space.